# retrieving a value from database then apply a split function on that

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, split-function

I am applying a split function when receiving a column value from a database table. And I want to proceed this process while `button_click` event.
**Here is my c# code.**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string st = "SELECT F_L FROM split_master";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(st, sqlcon);
      int count = 0;
      string[] word = st.Split();
      for (count = 0; count <= word.Length - 1; count++)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(word[count]);
      }
      cmd.Connection.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmd.Connection.Close();
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string st = "SELECT F_L FROM split_master";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(st, sqlcon);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader sqlread = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    while(sqlread.Read()){
        string[] word = sqlread["F_L"].ToString().Split();
        for (int count = 0; count <= word.Length; count++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(word[count]);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: hello @farrokh, i want to show my string with console.writeline Method.
please help

Comment: Hello @AnuragDixit, you should to just replace `MessageBox.Show` with `Console.WriteLine`, what's the problem ?

Comment: ,Actually it doesn't work, and i also want to split a string on spaces.

Comment: create a new topic(If not exist) and describe your problem and source code there